# change asynchronous for loop with delay to synchronous javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, delay, synchronous

I have async code for loop inside function that have a delay like that

```js
    const timeout = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
    async function sayHai() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          await timeout(1000);
          console.log("Hai");
          if ( (i%5) == 4 ) await timeout(30000);
      }
    }
    
    sayHai();
```

i have that code to produce as below :

```
hai delay 1 sec
hai delay 1 sec
hai delay 1 sec
hai delay 1 sec
hai delay 1 sec
delay 30 sec
hai delay 1 sec
hai delay 1 sec
hai delay 1 sec
hai delay 1 sec
hai delay 1 sec
```

I want the code to be synchronous because I want to use it on the console so I need the code to be executed sequentially

Comment: theres no synchronous sleep in javascript.

Comment: this will run sequentially too.

Comment: I apply it in a function that contains the process and the results ,process have not been completed but have already executed the next process

Comment: then post a [mcve] of that problem.

Comment: sounds like using a queue would be better.... And I am guessing the code above does not actually correctly modal the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is way to complicated. It can be simplified with a simple queue. Have a function that calls itself and uses a timeout for the next iteration.

```js
function run() {
  let cnt = 0;
  function next() {
    cnt++;
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleString())
    window.setTimeout(next, cnt % 5 == 0 ? 5000 : 1000);
  }
  next();
}

run();
```